# Exporting GEE colab results

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-colab, naip

I am new to GEE and Colab and have gotten code updated from https://github.com/RitikaPrasai/NAIP-aerial-imagery-file/blob/main/Final%20supervised%20classification%20of%20NAIP%20imagery-12%20December.ipynb that I updated to work in colab.

My problem arises when trying to export results. I know I am  probably having size limitations. I tried exporting to my google drive which appears to work but the tifs that result seem to be empty. I have spend way too many hours just trying to export data and would apprecizate help.

My code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ABV12ZSZgPcUCVQQGx9JHiXpVEqYvPr6?usp=sharing